# How do I detect which Window is obscuring another?

Tags: winapi

If I have the handles to two windows, how can I tell whether one is obscuring the other?  Obviously I can easily do a collision test, but how do I test / find out their "z order"?  The windows are from totally different apps.

I am probably missing something fairly obvious..

Comment: I wish installation programs did this.  I can't tell you how many times I've waited on an install because it displayed a prompt that somehow fell behind the main installation window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WindowFromPoint, (use a point bounded by one window, and see if you get back that window's handle, or the other one).

For partial obscuration, you can use the clipping system. I discuss this in more detail on my website [here](http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/w32tip72.htm)

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599(VS.85).aspx#zorder) talks about the Z ordering of windows. It doesn't mention a function to get the Z order directly, but it does point at `GetNextWindow()`, which given one window can return the next (or previous, don't let the name fool you) in the Z order. Using that, you should be able to figure it out.